# relatively short time sliding window

Tags: signal-processing, gaussian, measurement

I want to measure the frequency response function. 
to measure the FRF we should multiply the response signal to a window such as Gaussian or Hann windows. but in the below Patent they have claimed we use relatively short time sliding window.
I've studied the below US patent many times in these months:
http://s2.picofile.com/file/8282998818/_pat8854030.pdf.html

I really I can't understand how I can define the relatively short time sliding windows. 
by summary:
[page 4 & 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WToIi.jpg)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The terms in patents only need to be defined so that "one skilled in the art" is able to understand what they mean.  They don't need to have an explicit definition if their common usage definition is known.

In this instance, you maybe able to find a formal definition by looking at the patents cited during this patents prosecution.

That said, I think you might gain some understanding by looking to the definition of "time-domain window".

After reading this patent, I suspect "relatively short sliding time-domain window" means a time-domain window shorter than the period of the reference signal.

This patent may have some validity problems stemming from indefinite language issues.